# Alignment in itemize

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, itemize, dotfill

I need to align some elements within an itemize environment.
For example, each item contains a question and some space (with dots) for students' answer.

How can I have some elements within itemize properly aligned (for example each square root, each "=" sign, and each \dotfill ) ?

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Question 1 ( \, \, / 5)}
\textbf{Calcule} sans calculatrice:
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\sqrt{4900} = $\quad \dotfill\\
    \item $\sqrt{81}  = $\quad \dotfill\\
    \item $\sqrt{640000}  = $\quad \dotfill\\
    \item $\sqrt{144}  = $\quad \dotfill\\
    \item $\sqrt{0,16}  = $\quad \dotfill\\
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Question 2 ( \, \, / 5)}
\textbf{Donne} un encadrement à l'unité près des racines carrées ci-dessous:
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \makebox[60pt]{\dotfill}$< \sqrt{49} < $\makebox[60pt]{\dotfill}
\item \makebox[60pt]{\dotfill}$< \sqrt{490000} < $\makebox[60pt]{\dotfill}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe helpful: https://ctan.org/pkg/cloze

Comment: Off-topic: First of all I would not recommend to number the questions manually. If you want to use `\subsection` (or another heading level) for the questions, I would recommend to configure the command to produce the wanted output with automatic numbering, e.g., using `titlesec`. But there are also several packages for [exercises](https://ctan.org/topic/exercise), [exams](https://ctan.org/topic/exam) etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load the package [eqparbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) and use a macro s.a. `\eqmakebox` to keep the first element of a list in a table form. The macro is similar to `\makebox` with one difference: you provide a **tab** instead of width for a box. Then, the macro adapts widths of each box if the same tag is used. Here is example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize]{before*=\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Question 1 ( \, \, / 5)}

\textbf{Calcule} sans calculatrice:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \eqmakebox[Q1][r]{$\sqrt{4900} ={}$}\dotfill
  \item \eqmakebox[Q1][r]{$\sqrt{81} ={}$}\dotfill
  \item \eqmakebox[Q1][r]{$\sqrt{640000} ={}$}\dotfill
  \item \eqmakebox[Q1][r]{$\sqrt{144} ={}$}\dotfill
  \item \eqmakebox[Q1][r]{$\sqrt{0,16} ={}$}\dotfill
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Question 2 ( \, \, / 5)}

\textbf{Donne} un encadrement à l'unité près des racines carrées ci-dessous:
\begin{itemize}
\item \dotfill ${}<{}$\eqmakebox[Q2]{$\sqrt{49}$}${}<{}$\dotfill
\item \dotfill ${}<{}$\eqmakebox[Q2]{$\sqrt{490000}$}${}<{}$\dotfill
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 1.** If you want to add extra vertical space between lists and texts, I would also suggest to load [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), remove all instances of `\vspace{0.5cm}` and add the following line to preamble:

```
\setlist[itemize]{before*=\vspace{0.5cm}}
```

This will inject the code before each itemize env. This way you avoid repetition in code. There is similar option: `after*`, which injects a code after lists.

**EDIT 2.** I forgot to mention about one bit. You are not supposed to use double backslash `\\` at the end of a list item. It's because `\item` indicates to format and create space for new item, s.a. add a new line etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fits perfectly.

About my \\ after each item, it is to force some extra spacing between those items. Maybe there is a `between*` in the setlist option, I'll look!

Comment: Np. Regarding the spacing between items, there is a lot better way than \\. First, backslashes are unreliable. Second, you have to append every one at the end of each `\item`. I suggest you add [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package as I did in my example, then append `topsep=<length>` to `\setlist` after comma. `<length>` could absolute s.a. `12pt` or `1cm` or relative `4ex`. Considering my comment (EDIT 1), the full macro would be `\setlist[itemize]{before*=\vspace{0.5cm},topsep=4ex}`. You should see more space between list items.

Comment: Thanks Celdor!!!